# typo3 paginate widget starts not with uid 1, starts with the next uid after last uid

Tags: widget, typo3, fluid, extbase, pagination

I am using the paginate widget (copied the code from sysext, and change the path to my extension). I set it up an in my template like this:

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{therapeuts}" as="paginatedtherapeuts" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 9, insertAbove: 1, insertBelow: 1, maximumNumberOfLinks: 10, addQueryStringMethod: 'POST,GET'}">
    <f:for each="{paginatedtherapeuts}" as="therapeut">
    ...
    </f:for>
</f:widget.paginate>
```

the frontend shows 9 "entries" like it should show. but these Entries are empty. Checking this with f:debug shows the following:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResultprototypeobject (9 items)
0 => ...\Therapeutprototypepersistent entity (uid=17454, pid=0)
1 => ...\Therapeutprototypepersistent entity (uid=17455, pid=0)
2 => ...\Therapeutprototypepersistent entity (uid=17456, pid=0)
3 => ...\Therapeutprototypepersistent entity (uid=17457, pid=0)
4 => ...\Therapeutprototypepersistent entity (uid=17458, pid=0)
5 => ...\Therapeutprototypepersistent entity (uid=17459, pid=0)
6 => ...\Therapeutprototypepersistent entity (uid=17460, pid=0)
7 => ...\Therapeutprototypepersistent entity (uid=17461, pid=0)
8 => ...\Therapeutprototypepersistent entity (uid=17462, pid=0)
```

and this is wrong. I have got 17453 entries in the {therapeuts} object starting from uid 1 to 17453.

The widget.paginate now shows uids that doesn't exist. Why or what i am doing wrong, that the paginate widget does not start with uid 1 ??

thank you for any help

Comment: Which TYPO3 Version you are using?